Spring Webflux's WebClient not deserializing LocalDateTime even with "JavaTimeModule()" configured for the Jackson ObjectMapper
I have the following setup springBootVersion = "3.2.4" across all applications an libraries
Internal library Gradle dependencies in build.gradle
dependencies {
    api platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
}

Internal library Shared Jackson ObjectMapper
@AutoConfiguration
public class SharedAutoConfiguration {

  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
  protected static class ObjectMapperConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {

      return jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
          .modules(JsonMappers.modules())
          .featuresToDisable(JsonMappers.featuresToDisable())
          .build();
    }
  }
}

Internal library JsonMappers methods
public static List<Module> modules() {
  return List.of(new Jdk8Module(), new JavaTimeModule(), new ParameterNamesModule());
}

public static Object[] featuresToDisable() {
  return Stream.of(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS).toArray(Object[]::new);
}

Here's the WebClient config in the application that depends on the shared internal library and injects the ObjectMapper from the library
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebClientConfig {

  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient(
      final WebClient.Builder webclientBuilder) {

    return webclientBuilder
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .codecs(
            clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
              clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer
                  .defaultCodecs()
                  .jackson2JsonEncoder(
                      new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
              clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer
                  .defaultCodecs()
                  .jackson2JsonDecoder(
                      new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            })
        .build();
  }
}

And finally a controller in the application that utilizes the configured WebClient
  @GetMapping("/endpoint")
  public String someAction(final WebClient webClient) throws SomeCheckedException {
    try {
      ApiRequest requestBody = //{code that builds request body};

      ApiResponse<ResponseDTO> apiResponse =
          webClient
              .post()
              .uri("/some/external/api")
              .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))
              .retrieve()
              .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, ClientResponse::createException)
              .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ApiResponse<ResponseDTO>>() {})
              .block(); // block because the application is Spring MVC (not webflux)

      // Do whatever with apiResponse here
    
    } catch (WebClientResponseException ex) {
    
      ApiErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = ex.getResponseBodyAs(ApiErrorResponse.class);
    
      // Do whatever with apiErrorResponse
    }
  }

As you may notice, whenever the called API errors out, it's designed to return a json response body of the shape captured by ApiErrorResponse
The error json
{
  "timestamp":"2024-05-16T19:25:04.100012",
  "path":"/some/external/api",
  "requestId":"xxx",
  "status":"OK",
  "message":"some-message"
}

The error object - to which the Json should be deserialized
@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@FieldNameConstants
public class ApiErrorResponse {

  private final LocalDateTime timestamp;
  private final String path;
  private final String requestId;
  private final HttpStatus status;
  private final String message;

}

I have ObjectMapper Unit Tests that pass successfully - serialize & deserialize the LocalDateTime
  @Test
  void apiErrorResponse_serializationAndDeserialization_IsOK() throws JsonProcessingException {

    ApiErrorResponse error =
            ApiErrorResponse.builder()
                    .message("some-message")
                    .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .requestId("xxx")
                    .path("/some/external/api")
                    .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                    .build();

    String apiErrorResponseString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(error);
    System.out.println(apiErrorResponseString);

    Assertions.assertTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(apiErrorResponseString));

    ApiErrorResponse deserializedErrorResponse =
            objectMapper.readValue(apiErrorResponseString, new TypeReference<>() {});

    Assertions.assertEquals(error, deserializedErrorResponse);
  }

THE PROBLEM:
However the problem now is that with the WebClient the following line throws an exception;
ApiErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = ex.getResponseBodyAs(ApiErrorResponse.class);

Similarly this also fails with the same exception;
.onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, response -> response.bodyToMono(ApiErrorResponse.class).map(body -> new SomeException(body)))

The Exception;
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:271) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:211) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$initDecodeFunction$2(DefaultClientResponse.java:251) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.decodeBody(WebClientResponseException.java:253) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]

The Cause;
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling
 at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 35] (through reference chain: my.package.ApiErrorResponse -> my.package.ApiErrorResponseBuilder["timestamp"])

This is very strange to me because the following have already been done;

Add JavaTimeModule to ObjectMapper
ObjectMapper Unit Tests pass with LocalDateTime
Verify that the configured ObjectMapper is getting injected in the application
Configure WebClient codecs with the ObjectMapper

THE QUESTION:
Having done all the necessary steps highlighted above, what else is required to fix this?? I would really appreciate some pointers on this.
